# LinkedIn limiting number of views of public profile; requires joining/login for more views

Tags: linkedin, profile

My LinkedIn profile allows public viewing of my full profile. So even non-LinkedIn members should be able to see it, right?

But that's not what's happening. I've tested on multiple computers, browsers, and phones. And I've dumped cache to be sure I was starting a fresh test.

In all cases, LinkedIn insists on signing in to see the profile.

See screenshot for settings. Is there something I need to change in the "Customize Your Public Profile" settings? Or something I need to change elsewhere in LinkedIn? Or maybe I misunderstand LinkedIn's own explanation about how the public view works?

[image: LinkedIn Public View Settings]

Comment: This is not a reproducible error: I've just gone on your linkedin profile and I can see your profile including your profile summary, Experience, Volunteer Experience & Causes, Languages,Courses, Organizations, Skills, Education, Recommendations and Groups. **And I'm not logged in**

Comment: Wow! Any idea why we are having a different experience?

Comment: Spousal unit has also tested. The first time, he could see my profile. For subsequent views he has to log in.

Comment: I used incognito mode and I can see your profile just fine.

Comment: This is one of those things in which you can view the public profile just fine, but if you want to view a second one, it asks you to log in, probably based on a cookie.  This is a LinkedIn ploy, not anything to do with your individual profile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments that others could see my profile suggested that something other than my settings was the issue. Based on further research and testing, here are my findings:

- LinkedIn has limits on the number of times that you can view public
  profiles without logging in. https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/69654
- The LinkedIn counter appears to be tied to the IP address. Turning off
  Wi-Fi and switching to cellular generates a new IP address and "fresh"
  access.
- The LinkedIn interface can be deceiving. My first two or three
  views in cellular opened a clean view. On subsequent views, a LinkedIn
  "Join" window overlaid a dimmed out view of my profile. Then I
  noticed "See more" at the bottom of the screen. I scrolled and saw
  everything.

Comment: The [Commercial Use Limit](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/52950) linked in the link explains more about the limit. You may expand this answer by quoting from it.

Comment: This is good research. If you expand your answer with the information found by @AndrewT. and jonsca, it would be a great answer. There's also nothing wrong with _accepting_ your own answer.

Comment: @Andrew T. I did research the Commercial Use limit, but after reading it several times I determined that it applied when someone with a free account was logged in. I was concerned about nonmember public views, and disregarded the Commercial Use explanation. Your comment was helpful, so I will try to change the title of my post to reflect that login nuance.
  
@ Vidar - That was a good reminder for infrequent Stackexchangers like me.